# SQL Group By not working in Join

Tags: sql

I'm having an issue with the GROUP BY function. I tried using the DISTINCT function for my purposes, but all of my searching led me to try using the GROUP BY function.

I have 3 tables. Tbl1 and Tbl2 have the same Columns.
Tbl 3 has different columns, but I'm essentially trying to join all 3 tables together, which this query does correctly.

However, I'd like the resultset to exclude duplicates in one of the columns, Tbl3.A

I'm getting the error: Column 'DB1.dbo.Tbl2.C' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here's the full Query:

```
SELECT Tbl3.A, Tbl1.C, Tbl1.B
FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl1
LEFT JOIN
DB2.dbo.Tbl3 ON Tbl1.B = Tbl3.A
WHERE ….

UNION

SELECT Tbl3.A, Tbl2.C, Tbl2.B
FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl2 
LEFT JOIN 
DB2.dbo.Tbl3 ON Tbl2.B = Tbl3.A

WHERE …..

GROUP BY Tbl3.A
```

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: If you want to group by Tbl3.A, you have to aggregate columns Tbl1.C and Tbl1.B.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery.  Something like this:

```
SELECT A, MAX(C) as C, MAX(B) as B
FROM ((SELECT Tbl3.A, Tbl1.C, Tbl1.B
       FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl1 LEFT JOIN
            DB2.dbo.Tbl3
            ON Tbl1.B = Tbl3.A
       WHERE ….
      ) UNION
      (SELECT Tbl3.A, Tbl2.C, Tbl2.B
       FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl2  LEFT JOIN 
            DB2.dbo.Tbl3
            ON Tbl2.B = Tbl3.A
       WHERE …..
     )
    ) t
GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: @TomD . . . Then use `as` to give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NewTbl3.A, Tbl1.C, Tbl1.B
FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT Tbl3.A) AS NewTbl3
ON Tbl1.B = NewTbl3.A
WHERE ….

UNION

SELECT NewTbl3.A, Tbl2.C, Tbl2.B
FROM DB1.dbo.Tbl2 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT Tbl3.A) AS NewTbl3
ON Tbl2.B = NewTbl3.A

WHERE …..

GROUP BY NewTbl3.A
```